How to wrap a struct's data members type with `std::optional`?
Let's say I have a
struct Params {
   int member1;
   std::string member2;
   int member3 = 42;
   std::shared_ptr<std::string> member4;  
};

Is there a way to wrap each type with std::optional, so I get
struct MaybeParams {
   std::optional<int> member1;
   std::optional<std::string> member2;
   std::optional<int> member3;
   std::optional<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> member4;
};

In real life, the class Params has about 50 data members and is a private struct inside another class; and I can't modify their definition. I would also prefer a pure C++20 solution, except for the boost library.
I need this to make a universal function used to override some members of the Params, similar in spirit to what can be achieved in Python's named keyword parameters, with each parameter defaulted to "None".
Anyway, I believe we can't solve the problem, because my guts tell me that would require a C++ reflection. But I post the question here nevertheless, in hope that once again the SO community solve an "impossible" problem.

Further context:
I need the MaybeParams class for designated initializer list to have modifiedCopy function like this:
MyClass {
public:
  MyClass(const Params& pars): _pars(pars) {...}
...
private:
  Params _pars;
};

const MyClass modifiedCopy(const MyClass& reference, const MyClass::MaybeParams& what_to_modify);

int main() {
   const auto m1 = MyClass{.member1 = 1, .member2="ABC"};
   const MyClass m2 = modifiedCopy(m1, {
      .member2 = "XYZ",   
      .member4 = make_shared("XXX")
   });
}

I agree that in the ideal world it is better to have classes with fewer data members or have budget to refactor. If anyone knows how to get to that world - please let me know ;-)

This feels like a design problem, and not a code problem. Could it be designed so that you don't need to make all members individually std::optional?

If you can't modify the original struct I don't really see any option. But on the other hand it looks like refactoring/bugfising is needed anyway if the original Params do not initialize all their values (so reading from them before giving them a value is technically UB.

@Someprogrammerdude That may require magical "numbers" to indicate "not" set. And interpreting strings with length 0. Doable but fragile. Other than that I think making everything std::optional is the better idea.

it's not clear what you are doing now, how are the "unused" members initialized?

std::optional<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> member4; What is the advantage of making a shared pointer optional?

With magic_get, you might have some kind of reflection and turn Params as std::tuple. Then transforming std::tuple<Ts...> into std::tuple<std::optional<Ts>...> is relatively trivial.

@3CxEZiVlQ when the optional is empty, you don't replace the existing shared ptr

As std::shared_ptr can be nullptr, it's not efficient to be use as an std::optional argument. Similarly since std::string has empty state, there's no benefits in making it optional. As long as the class is an aggregate type, you can use BOOST.pfr to tie the members as a tuple of references. Converting the resultant tuple to tuple of optionals should not be a problem afterwards. But if you require to get named members in the result, any framework to use would have to provide an adhoc reflection mechanism.

The design problem seems solvable. To update Params::member2 (a std::string), you store &Params::member2 (a member pointer) together with std::string{"new value"}.
This pair could be stored in a ParamsUpdate<std::string> - templated because not every member is a std::string.  Derive this ParamsUpdate<T> from a ParamsUpdateBase and put all updates in a std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ParamsUpdateBase>>. ParamsUpdateBase of course has a virtual void apply_to(Params&), that's why you need to store a pointer.
C++17 Class Template Argument Deduction allows you to deduce T from ParamsUpdate(&Params::member2, "new value") but you'll need to write a deduction guide for that.

C++ does not currently have reflection or metaclasses. There is no way to magically make a version of the class with every member individually optional.
Likely this is a design problem: Why do you need this in the first place? (See also What is the XY problem?) Can you refactor this code to not need a struct with 50 data members? How would you use a MaybeParams class, do you have default values for the parameters in mind?
Often for this sort of use case most members do not have to be optional and there's a default value that makes sense.

I've added more context to the question
